# JAVA: Game of Craps making sure what printed is correct

Tags: java, random, dice

I have an assignment for my programming course. I have only one issue which I cannot figure out.

My instructions are the following: Write a program that simulates how often a player would win if they rolled the dice 100 times. If the players rolls a 7, or 11 they win

My Problem is the following: My program is showing that I'm winning more times than I should be. I only want my program to print out the message that the user has won, if they have a seven or an eleven, but that isn't happening. Could anyone give me some advice on what I might need to do?

Below is my code. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

```
    @author Jordan Navas
    @version 1.0

  COP2253    Workshop7
 File Name: Craps.java
 */

import java.util.Random;

public class Craps 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Random rand = new Random();
  int gamesWon=0;
  int gamesLost=0;

  for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
  {
     craps(rand);
     if(craps(rand))
     {
               gamesWon++;
     }
     else{
           gamesLost++;
     }
  }
    System.out.println("Games You Have Won: " + gamesWon);
    System.out.println("Games You Have Lost: " + gamesLost);

}    
public static boolean craps(Random rand)
{
    int firstDice = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
    int secondDice = rand.nextInt(6+1);
    int sumOfDies = firstDice + secondDice;
        System.out.print("[" + firstDice + "," + secondDice + "]");

        if (sumOfDies == 7 || sumOfDies == 11)
        {
            System.out.println(sumOfDies + " You Won! Congratulations! You Won! Congratulations! ");
            return true;
        } else if(sumOfDies == 2 || sumOfDies == 3 || sumOfDies == 12)
         {
            System.out.println(sumOfDies + " Congratulations! You Lost! ");
            return false;
         }

    int point = sumOfDies;
            System.out.print("Point: " + point + " ");


    if (sumOfDies == point)
    {
        System.out.println(sumOfDies + " You Won! Congratulations! You Won! Congratulations!");
        return true;
    } else
      {
        System.out.println(sumOfDies + " Congratulations! You Lost! ");
        return false;
      }


      }
    }
```

Comment: `if (sumOfDies == point)` will always return `true`

Comment: Doesn't the return false negate that, though? Is that not good enough? Should I just delete that part of the coding?

Comment: this code will return `true` for anything other than `2,3 or 12`

Comment: You check `if (sumOfDies == point)` immediately after saying `int point = sumOfDies;`. You're basically checking if a value is equal to itself. That check will *always* be true.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you're saying. How do I change the if statement of (sumOfDoes == 2) et cetera, to be everything else but 7 or 11. Those are the only sum of Dies that can be a win.

Comment: what do u want to happen if the sun of dice is other than 2,3,12,7 and 11?

Comment: Unless the sum of the dice is 7 or 11, I want to print out a message saying that the user lost the game.

Comment: I just didn't know how to write a condition that would cover every number BUT seven or eleven.

Comment: @J.Nav `if(sumOfDies != 7 && sumOfDies != 11)`

Comment: @resueman Because the exclamation point means the opposite of! Of course!

Comment: @resueman Brilliant! It works perfectly now. Thank you so much. It always goes back to the most basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need following if condition in your code.

```
if (sumOfDies == point) { System.out.println(sumOfDies + " You Won! Congratulations! You Won! Congratulations!"); return true; }
```

infact all you need in your code is following condition.

```
if (sumOfDies == 7 || sumOfDies == 11) { System.out.println(sumOfDies + " You Won! Congratulations! You Won! Congratulations! "); return true; }
 else  { System.out.println(sumOfDies + " Congratulations! You Lost! "); return false; }
```

here is how your function should work:

```
    public static boolean craps(Random rand) {
      int firstDice = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
      int secondDice = rand.nextInt(6+1); 
      int sumOfDies = firstDice + secondDice; 
      System.out.print("[" + firstDice + "," + secondDice + "]"); 
      if (sumOfDies == 7 || sumOfDies == 11) { 
            System.out.println(sumOfDies + " You Won! Congratulations! You Won! Congratulations! ");
            return true;
      } else {
            System.out.println(sumOfDies + " Congratulations! You Lost! "); 
            return false; 
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried taking it out already, but it messed up the parentheses.